# How do I prevent Bazel from overriding the value of builtin macros __DATE__ and __TIME__?

Tags: bazel

Their value is being changed to `redacted` - how does one undo this? I've tried to use `--define` on the command line but it is not bringing them back.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/12ebd7bb4905f0fdabdaa6db4a22dab7fd95dea8/tools/cpp/windows_cc_toolchain_config.bzl):

```
determinism_feature = feature(
            name = "determinism",
            enabled = True,
            flag_sets = [
                flag_set(
                    actions = [ACTION_NAMES.c_compile, ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile],
                    flag_groups = [
                        flag_group(
                            flags = [
                                "/wd4117",
                                "-D__DATE__=\"redacted\"",
                                "-D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\"",
                                "-D__TIME__=\"redacted\"",
                            ] + (["-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined"] if ctx.attr.compiler == "clang-cl" else []),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
```

Read the documentation about [features](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#features).